# Why some recently added fields are not initialized by constructor

Tags: grails, groovy

Groovy will all it's dynamic possibilities is still new to me and I'm kind of lost why below code does not work.

```
def luke = new FooPerson(firstName: "Luke", lastName: "Skywalker", initials: "LS", login: "luke", password: "luke" )
```

Above gives me proper values for *firstName*, *lastName* and *initials* and for *login* and *password* I get null.

If with above code I call

```
luke.setLogin("luke")
luke.setPassword("luke")
```

I will get proper value of all fields.

All five fields are declared in class

```
class Person {

   static constraints = {
   }

   String firstName
   String lastName
   String initials
   String login
   String password

   }
```

that my lovely FooPerson inherits from. My problematic fields were not initially in the Person class. I added them recently and obviously this causes groovy some stress.

Of course I can work around this, but I want to understand **WHY** it's working that weird way.

Comment: This should not be as issue at all. It works as expected in Grails 2.2.4. Which version of Grails do you use?

Comment: 2.2.3 I'll check with 2.2.4 and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @dmahapatro **upgrading to grails 2.2.4 solves the problem**. 
I've looked into [release notes of Grails 2.2.4](http://jira.grails.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=13466&styleName=Html&projectId=10020&Create=Create&atl_token=BAXD-D6T1-E9YH-5BK8%7C9784073a2d70094ea4f0a9756d4c37060ea535fd%7Clout) and I don't see anything meaningful that could be connected to this, but it solves the problem.

Comment: FYI. This isn't a problem with 2.2.3 as well. I bet something else was bothering you.

Comment: @dmahapatro I did upgrade to 2.2.4, then upgraded my app and it worked like a charm.